# While creating sstable in Cassandra, I get "Can't find yaml file" error

Tags: cassandra-2.0

This program creates sstables to be used along with sstableloader in cassandra. But, when I run this program, it gives me this error:

Cannot locate cassandra.yaml
Fatal configuration error; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.

I am running Apache Cassandra v 2.1.2 on a 32 bit ubuntu 12.04 machine. I found a plausible solution on datastax website, [link here](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/issue-with-cassandra-on-windows), but the I can't follow the exact solution

Anyone has an idea what to do next?

```
    package com.cassandra;

    import static org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.bytes;
    import static org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen.decompose;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType;
    import org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType;
    import org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType;
    import org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType.Builder;
    import org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType;
    import org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner;
    import org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter;

    public class SStableBuilder {

           static String csvfilename = "records.csv";

           public static void main(String[] args) {

                  try {
                         buildSStables();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         e.printStackTrace();
                  }
           }

           public static void buildSStables() throws Exception {

                  String keyspace = "samplekey";
                  String table = "users";
                  File directory = new File(keyspace + "/" + table);

                  if (!directory.exists()) {
                         directory.mkdirs();
               }

                  List<AbstractType<?>> compositeColumnValues = new ArrayList<AbstractType<?>>();
                  compositeColumnValues.add(AsciiType.instance);
                  compositeColumnValues.add(AsciiType.instance);
                  CompositeType compositeColumn = CompositeType.getInstance(compositeColumnValues);
                  System.out.println("yahahahaha");
                  SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter bulkWriter = new SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter(
                               directory, new Murmur3Partitioner(), keyspace, table,
                               compositeColumn, null, 64);

                  // Create a single timestamp for each insert
                  long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;

                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfilename));
                  String line;
                  int lineNumber = 1;
                  CsvEntry entry = new CsvEntry();

                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                         if (entry.parse(line, lineNumber)) {

                               ByteBuffer uuid = ByteBuffer.wrap(decompose(entry.key));
                               bulkWriter.newRow(uuid);

                               Builder builder = compositeColumn.builder();
                               builder.add(bytes(entry.firstname));
                               builder.add(bytes("firstname"));
                               bulkWriter.addColumn(builder.build(), bytes(entry.firstname), timestamp);

                               builder = compositeColumn.builder();
                               builder.add(bytes(entry.firstname));
                               builder.add(bytes("lastname"));
                               bulkWriter.addColumn(builder.build(), bytes(entry.lastname), timestamp);

                               builder = compositeColumn.builder();
                               builder.add(bytes(entry.firstname));
                               builder.add(bytes("password"));
                               bulkWriter.addColumn(builder.build(), bytes(entry.password), timestamp);

                               builder = compositeColumn.builder();
                               builder.add(bytes(entry.firstname));
                               builder.add(bytes("age"));
                               bulkWriter.addColumn(builder.build(), bytes(String.valueOf(entry.age)), timestamp);

                               builder = compositeColumn.builder();
                               builder.add(bytes(entry.firstname));
                               builder.add(bytes("email"));
                               bulkWriter.addColumn(builder.build(), bytes(entry.email), timestamp);



                         }
                         lineNumber++;
                  }

                  reader.close();
                  System.out.println("Success");
                  bulkWriter.close();
                  System.exit(0);
           }

           static class CsvEntry {
                  UUID key;
                  String firstname;
                  String lastname;
                  String password;
                  long age;
                  String email;

                  boolean parse(String line, int lineNumber) {
                         // Ghetto csv parsing
                         String[] columns = line.split(",");
                         if (columns.length != 6) {
                               System.out.println(String.format(
                                             "Invalid input '%s' at line %d of %s", line,
                                             lineNumber, csvfilename));
                               return false;
                         }
                         try {
                               key = UUID.fromString(columns[0].trim());
                               firstname = columns[1].trim();
                               lastname = columns[2].trim();
                               password = columns[3].trim();
                               age = Long.parseLong(columns[4].trim());
                               email = columns[5].trim();
                               return true;
                         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                               System.out.println(String.format(
                                             "Invalid number in input '%s' at line %d of %s", line,
                                             lineNumber, csvfilename));
                               return false;
                         }
                  }
           }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That config is loaded from a URL specified by system property 'cassandra.config'. You can set that pointing to your file.

If you do not set that, it looks for the default 'cassandra.yaml' as a class loader resource. You can make that succeed by making sure your CLASSPATH contains a path to a directory with cassandra.yaml in it.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/0ce9abd78c8712ad4fba28734214b18f617a2aac/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/YamlConfigurationLoader.java#L55-L68

Comment: I had the system property 'cassandra.config' to the yaml file location. Now it has started giving some more errors saying that its an invalid yaml file. It can't figure out some variables mentioned in the yaml file.